# How to update the firmware of a Cardo Packtalk Slim (or Freecom) on linux (natively or through a virtual machine)?

Tags: debian, kvm, qemu, libvirt, firmware

The firmware updating software for Cardo bluetooth communication systems  (Packtalk, freecom,...)  are only available for Windows and Mac OS.  I do not have these OSes running natively.  Is it possible to get my Cardo devices firmware updated through my Debian OS. I have been unsuccesful installing the Cardo Update.exe file through wine (version 5.0.3) with following error:  'Installation error. Please reboot and try again.'

> 002c:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class
> {a2a9545d-a0c2-42b4-9708-a0b2badd77c8} not registered
> 002c:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class
> {a2a9545d-a0c2-42b4-9708-a0b2badd77c8} not registered
> 002c:err:ole:create_server class
> {a2a9545d-a0c2-42b4-9708-a0b2badd77c8} not registered
> 002c:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object
> {a2a9545d-a0c2-42b4-9708-a0b2badd77c8} could be created for context
> 0x17

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by Tonphai's solution I tried to find one with Virtualbox.

Used the following command to get info on connected USB devices. Make sure the Cardo pack is on. You will need to have a working guest Windows installation on Virtualbox.

```
lsusb
```

My output was:

```
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 2685:0900 Cardo Systems Inc. Cardo Device
```

In the Virtualbox Manager go to Settings for this Windows virtual machine, select USB. I left the USB 3.0 controller on. Create new USB filter and enter some meaningful text for the name. I used "Cardo (manual)", Vendor ID would be **2685**, Product ID would be **0900**. Serial number I set as **0** and port as **4**.

[image]

Now at first this didn't seem to work but after restarting my linux machine it seems to be fine. To make sure the USB devices are recognized make sure that your user is part of the **vboxusers** group

```
sudo adduser $USER vboxusers
```

Make sure to install the latest Virtualbox Guest Additions by following the instructions here: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html

Install the Cardo updater program for Windows: https://www.cardosystems.com/download-cardo-updater/

Once you start your Windows Guest VM go to the VB menu and select Devices - USB and select the Cardo device that should hopefully be listed.
This should make the Cardo install software to recognize your device and update its firmware.

Hope it works for you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was able to update the firmware of my Cardo units (2 Packtalk Slim) from the original version (4.2) to the newest version to date (5.7). I achieved it in Debian through a virtual machine running Windows 10 Pro. It did not update out of the box as it required me to load (attach) and unload (detach) multiple xml files during the firmware updating process. In retrospect, a walk in the park.

For virtualization on Debian, KVM (QEMU, libvirt) seems to be the way to go. To install it:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu-system libvirt-clients libvirt-daemon-system virt-manager
```

virt-manager has a gui that makes it easy to create and run a VM.  I installed a Windows 10 Pro .iso onto it. After which I was able to run it as a guest OS.

The Cardo Update software available from cardosystems website installed flawlessly on the guest OS (Win10).

The first hurdle was to get the USB Host Device (the Cardo unit) recognized by the guest OS. To do so, connect it and run the lsusb command in a terminal console on your host OS (Debian):

```
lsusb
```

> Bus 001 Device 035: ID **2685:0900** Cardo Peripheral Systems LTD
> [Packtalk Bold Bluetooth Motorcycle Intercom]

Take note of the vendor and the product id.  Here the vendor id being **2685** and the product id being **0900**.

Time to create our first (1/3) .xml file to attach to our VM. Let's name it 'usb_device_cardo.xml' and let's place it in our home folder of our host OS (Debian). It should contain the following:

```
<hostdev mode="subsystem" type="usb" managed="yes">
  <source>
    <vendor id="0x2685"/>
    <product id="0x0900"/>
  </source>
  <address type="usb" bus="0" port="4"/>
</hostdev>
```

Let's test if the cardo unit gets recognised. While the guest OS (win10) is running, open a terminal console on the host OS (Debian) and as root, run  the following command (replace 'win10' with the name of your VM):

```
virsh attach-device win10 --file usb_device_cardo.xml --current
```

> Device attached successfully

Your Cardo device will become available on your guest OS (win10). Let's **detach** it before running the Cardo Update software:

```
virsh detach-device win10 --file usb_device_cardo.xml
```

Device detached successfully

Once the Cardo Update software is running we can reattach it to start the firmware update:

```
virsh attach-device win10 --file usb_device_cardo.xml --current
```

The firmware update will start but will quickly come to a halt and the usb will seem to have been ejected from the guest OS (win10). If you run lsusb again in a terminal on the host OS (Debian) you will see that the Cardo device has a new product id (0901 instead of 0900 in my case.) It is time to create the second (2/3) .xml file to attach to our VM. Let's call it 'usb_device_cardo_2.xml'. It should be similar to the previous one except for an updated product id (**0x0901**) and port address (**5**):

```
<hostdev mode="subsystem" type="usb" managed="yes">
  <source>
    <vendor id="0x2685"/>
    <product id="0x0901"/>
  </source>
  <address type="usb" bus="0" port="5"/>
</hostdev>
```

Let's attach it before the firmware update times out.  In a terminal on the host OS (Debian) run:

```
virsh attach-device win10 --file usb_device_cardo_2.xml --current
```

> Device attached successfully

The firmware update will continue until it once again will come to a halt and 'eject' the device on the guest OS (win10).

Run lsusb again on the host OS (Debian) and the Cardo device will once again have a new product id (0001 in my case). Time to create the third and final .xml file, 'usb_device_cardo_3.xml' with an updated product id (**0x0001**) and address port (**6**):

```
<hostdev mode="subsystem" type="usb" managed="yes">
  <source>
    <vendor id="0x2685"/>
    <product id="0x0001"/>
  </source>
  <address type="usb" bus="0" port="6"/>
</hostdev>
```

Again as root in the terminal on the Host OS (Debian):

```
virsh attach-device win10 --file usb_device_cardo_3.xml --current
```

> Device attached successfully

To complete the firmware update you might have to attach/detach back and forth between the three different xml files with the "**virsch attach-device**" command. To know which one to attach, simply run **lsusb** on your Host OS (Debian) and attach the xml file with the identical product id (0x0900, 0x901 or 0x0001 in my case).

Firmware updated !  Let me know if it helped !